# Strange system sudden/instant restart issue, not related to heat?

Tags: shutdown

So I use a desktop computer and the way the tower is designed, there are small holes on the top - one of those CyberPower towers; anyway, today when I was taking the VGA from my monitor to put it on my tv as i always do for viewing there, I knocked a bottle of water I had forgot even had water in it that was open over and a SMALL BIT fell right into the desktop through those holes.

Now, I didn't see any sparks or any of that weird stuff; when I first turned the PC on afterwards as I shut it off right when it happened, it wouldn't display anything..at all. It was booting, as I heard the little ring sound for the windows login screen, but no display. Black.

Left it for 40 minutes or so untouched, booted just fine then; used the computer for an hour or so, all I did was listen to some music on youtube. Everything worked fine.

Suddenly, the screen goes black and the computer repeatedly restarts itself - everytime it hits the point after the boot screen for the login screen, it goes black..like it did at first. I left it off for a couple of minutes, boot it and it, yet again, boots up just fine - and then, after a couple of minutes, it yet again does it.

Now it's off and I'm leaving it that way until I find some help. Seems like the longer I leave it off, the longer it stays on. What did that water do? Burn a censor or something? I checked the temps when I managed to get on the second time and everything seemed fine, even up till the sudden restart.